# Python interpreter vs IDLE memory allocation

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle

I recently found out that the following snippet:

```
d = {1:"one" , 2:"two"}
id1 = id(d)

del(d)

d = {1:"one" , 2:"two"}
id2 = id(d)

print(id1==id2)
```

If it's executed via python interpreter (e.g. using terminal) returns `True` and if it's run in the IDLE Shell returns `False`.

[image]

I am aware that IDLE it's (more or less) an integrated dev environment written in Python , but I would really like to know what happens behind the scenes. Thanks .

Comment: when i run on REPL , it returned true, which infact is correct.On which specific IDLE you got  false?

Comment: The reuse of immutable objects depends on the implementation, python version and even release, and execution mode.  In interactive mode, each statement is treated like a separate file and compiled and executed by itself.  In 'file' or batch mode, multiple statements are compiled and then executed together.  When IDLE *simulates* interactive mode, each statement is compiled by itself in the IDLE process but then executed with an exec() call in a separate execution process running in batch mode.  IDLE itself has nothing to do with how python in the second process reused objects.

Comment: To summarize, the title here should be something "Python interactive vs exec() in batch mode memory use".  Originally, and still with the command line -n switch, IDLE did the exec() call in its own process.  But suggested title would still apply.